# moving folders between 2 SharePoint 2010 sites using robocopy

Tags: batch-file, command-line, sharepoint-2010, robocopy, file-length

I am trying to move a series of folders between two SharePoint 2010 sites but am not able to do so because the file paths are too long. I read online that robocopy might be able to solve the problem but can't quite get it to work.

I have mapped both sites to my computer and am using the file path from windows explorer of the mapped sites.

I enter into my command line:

```
robocopy https://sharepoint.company.com/area/team/project 
https://sharepoint.company.com/area/team/team name/project folder \e
```

The error I get is: Invalid parameter #3: "\e"

I think the issue may be to do with using robocopy with mapped drives, because when I did it with two files on my desktop it worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `RoboCopy` options as noted when reading the output information resulting from `RoboCopy /?` use the forward slash, i.e. `/E`. It should also be noted that locations containing whitespace should be enclosed between doublequotes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added in double quotes where there was whitespace and changed to /E. I am now getting the message that “C:\WINDOWS\system32\https:\company.com\team\area\project\folder” The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Do you know what the issue is?

Comment: Yes, you do not have a directory named `folder` in the location `C:\WINDOWS\system32\https:\company.com\team\area\project`!

Comment: Sorry, the project was a folder - I just added another one in and I still receive the same error message for both paths (source and destination). Is it to do with C:\Windowns\system32\https:? and the fact that I am referencing two folders that although mapped to my computer are not hosted there?

Comment: Windows does not allow **`:`** characters in file and directory names, so I do not see how that location can possibly exist! _You say that the directories are mapped, so it may be prudent to use the mapped paths in your command!_

Comment: Ok thank you, got it working now. Do you know if there is anyway for it to ignore the maximum file size limit? Or is this something that is set by the SharePoint administrator?

Comment: As far as I know, the supported limit is around 250MB. I think the the Admin however can increase it up to an absolute maximum of 2GB.

Comment: When you use a file explorer or file explorer-based utility to move files that are stored in SharePoint, you're actually using [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) via the WebClient service on your local computer. By default, a registry setting on your client computer (not on the SharePoint servers) restricts WebDAV to moving files of no more than 50 MB.

Comment: Thanks Compo! Thriggle, do you know how I can change this setting?